# Could not get the storage format of the medium '..\macOS_10.14.4.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtualbox, installation, iso-image

I am trying to install MacOS on Windows 10. I use Oracle VM virtual box. My MacOS file had `.dmg` format that when I used it at the first time I got this error message:

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! system halted
```

So I used AnytoIso software and changed the format of my file into the `.ISO` format and retried installation, but I got this new error message:

```
Failed to open the disk image file D:\macOS.Mojave.10.14.4\macOS_10.14.4_Mojave.iso.

Could not get the storage format of the medium 'D:\macOS.Mojave.10.14.4\macOS_10.14.4_Mojave.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
Callee: IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).